# What is the best way to allow a standard user to view all donations entered in Salesforce?

Tags: permission-sets

I have two users with a standard user profile (User1/User2) that need to be able to view all donations.  When user1 enters a new donation it doesn't show up in user2 search results vice versa.  What is the best way to allow a standard user to see all donations?  Permission sets??

Thanks,
Dee

Comment: -We are using Salesforce Non-Profit CRM

Answer (score 0):

Since I assume you have other standard users who don't need to see this information at all, Sharing Groups and Sharing Rules would be the proper approach to handle this use case. See [Tips and Hints for Sharing Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_sharing_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_sharing_cheatsheet/) for instructions on how to set this up. Permission sets would only be needed if the users in the Sharing Group didn't already have the permissions needed to view or edit the objects and fields you want them to have access to. In this particular case, they seem to have access to them, but not to the actual records since they're not the owners and need to share the records.

Comment: crmprogdev, is there a naming convention for Permission Sets label & API-name?  I created a permission set and the label is "View Donations" and the API is View_Donations.  No results are found for View Donations when I do a search, however, it shows up under Permission Set Assignments.  Should I enabled it for the two users.  It seem like a missed a step.  Any suggestions?

Comment: See my revised answer above. I think that should point you in the proper direction. Your users already have the object and field permissions they need. What they don't have is record sharing.